# evacuation modelling in NetLogo

Tags: netlogo

I am modelling an evacuation model from a simple plan with 4 rooms and one corridor. I have a problem for navigate agents from rooms to corridor and from corridor to main exit. would you please guide me.[image]

The codes that I wrote are there:

```
  globals [
  wall
  window
  door
  goal-x goal-y
  n
]

patches-own [path?]
turtles-own [direction
  fast?

  other-nearby]

to setup
  clear-all

    setup-patches

   set-default-shape turtles "person" ;makes them look like people
   ask n-of number-room1 patches with [pxcor < 71 and pycor < 79 and pxcor > 0 and pycor > 50 and pcolor = black]  ; makes turtles sprout on black patches = room1
  [
  sprout 1 [

      set size 5              ;; setting turtle size
      facexy 124 79 ; initial direction faceing
      set direction 1
      set color yellow     ;initial color

    ]
    ]

  ask n-of number-room2 patches with [pxcor < 112 and pycor < 79 and pxcor > 71 and pycor > 50 and pcolor = black]  ; makes turtles sprout on black patches= room2
  [
  sprout 1 [

      set size 5              ;; setting turtle size
      facexy 124 79 ; initial direction faceing
      set direction 1
      set color yellow     ;initial color

    ]
  ]



  ask n-of number-room3 patches with [pxcor < 82 and pycor < 36 and pxcor > 0 and pycor > 0 and pcolor = black]  ; makes turtles sprout on black patches= room3
  [
  sprout 1 [
      set size 5              ;; setting turtle size
      facexy 124 79 ; initial direction faceing
      set direction 1
      set color yellow     ;initial color
      ]
   ]



   ask n-of number-room4 patches with [pxcor < 132 and pycor < 36 and pxcor > 82 and pycor > 0 and pcolor = black]  ; makes turtles sprout on black patches= room4
 [
 sprout 1 [

      set size 5              ;; setting turtle size
      facexy 124 79 ; initial direction faceing
      set direction 1
      set color yellow     ;initial color

    ]
    ]


  reset-ticks
 end


to setup-patches

  draw-wall;wall, Windows and Doors
  draw-exit

    ;Labels
  ask patch 35 54[
    set plabel-color white
    set plabel "Room1"
  ]
  ask patch 90 54[
    set plabel-color white
    set plabel "Room2"
  ]
  ask patch 77 44[
    set plabel-color white
    set plabel "Corridor"
  ]
   ask patch 41 13[
    set plabel-color white
    set plabel "Room3"
  ]
   ask patch 105 13[
    set plabel-color white
    set plabel "Room4"
  ]

end

  to draw-wall
  ask patches with [pxcor <= 120.42 and pxcor >= 0 and pycor = 79]
    [set pcolor blue]
  ask patches with [pxcor <= 132 and pxcor >= 129.57 and pycor = 79]
    [set pcolor blue]
  ask patches with [pycor <= 79 and pycor >= 0 and pxcor = 132]
    [set pcolor blue]
  ask patches with [pycor <= 79 and pycor >= 0 and pxcor = 0]
    [set pcolor blue]

  ask patches with [pxcor <= 34.43 and pxcor >= 0 and pycor = 0]
    [set pcolor blue]
  ask patches with [pxcor <= 132 and pxcor >= 43.58 and pycor = 0]
    [set pcolor blue]
  ask patches with [pxcor <= 112 and pxcor >= 108.57 and pycor = 50]
    [set pcolor blue]
  ask patches with [pxcor <= 49.42 and pxcor >= 0 and pycor = 50]
    [set pcolor blue]
   ask patches with [pxcor <= 84.425 and pxcor >= 79.575 and pycor = 36]
    [set pcolor blue]
   ask patches with [pxcor <= 70.425 and pxcor >= 0 and pycor = 36]
    [set pcolor blue]
  ask patches with [pxcor <= 132 and pxcor >= 93.575 and pycor = 36]
    [set pcolor blue]

   ask patches with [pycor <= 79 and pycor >= 50 and pxcor = 71]
    [set pcolor blue]
  ask patches with [pycor <= 79 and pycor >= 50 and pxcor = 112]
    [set pcolor blue]
  ask patches with [pycor <= 36 and pycor >= 0 and pxcor = 82]
    [set pcolor blue]
   ask patches with [pxcor <= 99.42 and pxcor >= 58.57 and pycor = 50]
    [set pcolor blue]

  end

to draw-exit
  ;room1
  ask patches with [pxcor <= 58.57 and pxcor >= 49.42 and pycor = 50]
    [set pcolor green]
  ;room2
  ask patches with [pxcor <= 108.57 and pxcor >= 99.42 and pycor = 50]
    [set pcolor green]
  ;room3
  ask patches with [pxcor <= 79.575 and pxcor >= 70.425 and pycor = 36]
    [set pcolor green]
  ;room4
  ask patches with [pxcor <= 93.575 and pxcor >= 84.425 and pycor = 36]
    [set pcolor green]

  ;main exit
    ask patches with [pxcor <= 129.57 and pxcor >= 120.42 and pycor = 79]
    [set pcolor red]

  ;second exit
 ask patches with [pxcor <= 43.58 and pxcor >= 34.43 and pycor = 0]
    [set pcolor red]
 end


to go
  ask turtles [walk]
  tick
end

to walk
  let room1 patches with [pxcor < 71 and pycor < 79 and pxcor > 0 and pycor > 50]
  let room2 patches with [pxcor < 112 and pycor < 79 and pxcor > 71 and pycor > 50]
  let room3 patches with [pxcor < 82 and pycor < 36 and pxcor > 0 and pycor > 0]
  let room4 patches with [pxcor < 132 and pycor < 36 and pxcor > 82 and pycor > 0]
  let corridor patches with [pxcor < 132 and pycor < 50 and pxcor > 0 and pycor > 36]
  let exitpoint patches with [pxcor < 132 and pycor < 79 and pxcor > 112 and pycor > 50]

  ask turtles-on room1
  [face one-of patches with [pxcor <= 58.6 and pxcor >= 49.42 and pycor = 50]
    fd 0.5
  ]

  ask turtles-on room2
    [ face one-of patches with [pxcor <= 108.6 and pxcor >= 99.5 and pycor = 50]
    fd 0.5
  ]
  ask turtles-on room3
    [ face one-of patches with [pxcor <= 79 and pxcor >= 71 and pycor = 36]
    fd 0.5
  ]
  ask turtles-on room4
    [ face one-of patches with [pxcor <= 93.6 and pxcor >= 84.5 and pycor = 36]
    fd 0.5
  ]

  ask turtles-on corridor
  [ face one-of patches with [pxcor <= 132 and pxcor >= 112 and pycor = 50]
    fd 1
  ]
  ask turtles-on exitpoint
  [ face one-of patches with [pxcor <= 129 and pxcor >= 121 and pycor = 79]
    fd 1
  ]
   end
```

I could navigate agents from rooms to door of each room but I want to enter them in the corridor then from corridor to main exit.

Comment: What happens if you simply move them forward by 0.5 if they are on a door patch?

Answer (score 1):

I just modified your code by adding a "doors" variable underneath "walk". This tells the turtles that touch a green patch - your doors - to take two steps forward into the corridor. Once they are in the corridor they already have commands to move toward the exitpoint.

```
   to walk
      let room1 patches with [pxcor < 71 and pycor < 79 and pxcor > 0 and pycor > 50]
      let room2 patches with [pxcor < 112 and pycor < 79 and pxcor > 71 and pycor > 50]
      let room3 patches with [pxcor < 82 and pycor < 36 and pxcor > 0 and pycor > 0]
      let room4 patches with [pxcor < 132 and pycor < 36 and pxcor > 82 and pycor > 0]
      let corridor patches with [pxcor < 123 and pycor < 50 and pxcor > 0 and pycor > 36]
      let exitpoint patches with [pxcor < 130 and pycor < 80 and pxcor > 122 and pycor > 38]
      let doors patches with [pcolor = green]

      ask turtles-on room1
      [face one-of patches with [pxcor <= 58.6 and pxcor >= 49.42 and pycor = 50]
        fd 0.5
      ]

      ask turtles-on room2
        [ face one-of patches with [pxcor <= 108.6 and pxcor >= 99.5 and pycor = 50]
        fd 0.5
      ]
      ask turtles-on room3
        [ face one-of patches with [pxcor <= 79 and pxcor >= 71 and pycor = 36]
        fd 0.5
      ]
      ask turtles-on room4
        [ face one-of patches with [pxcor <= 93.6 and pxcor >= 84.5 and pycor = 36]
        fd 0.5

  ]

  ask turtles-on corridor
  [ face one-of patches with [pxcor <= 130 and pxcor >= 125 and pycor = 45]
    fd 1
  ]
  ask turtles-on exitpoint
  [ face one-of patches with [pxcor <= 129 and pxcor >= 121 and pycor = 79]
    fd 1
  ]


  ask turtles-on doors
  [ face one-of patches with [pxcor = 77 and pycor = 44 ]
    fd 2
 ]
```